# How to Find Optimal Way to Allocate a Budget?

Tags: optimization

How can I find the optimal or close to optimal way to allocate a budget if I have revenue and spending data?

I was thinking of using linear programming, but I'm assuming it wouldn't work as the relationship between revenue and spending isn't constant and there aren't really any constants aside from the amount being spent having to be positive.

Would a multivariate time-series analysis work?